# How to pipe/redirect the final stdout of a NCurse command?

Tags: c++, unix, ncurses

I have a command that displays Ncurses stuffs (`initscr`, `printw`, `addch`, ...). That's okay.

At the end (`endwin`), I want to "output" (`std::cout << "some string"`) a string to be processed by other command (or maybe redirected to a stream).
I ***want*** to do something like this :

```
my-ncurse-command | any-other-command
my-ncurse-command > some-stream
```

Problem is : my ncurses display is captured by the pipe or the redirect, not only the final string.

Is there a way to allow that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `initscr()`, use `newterm()`. If you are already using `newterm` it's just a matter of supplying a different output stream than `stdout`.

`initscr()` is equivalent to:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

WINDOW* myinitscr() {
    newterm(getenv("TERM"), stdout, stdin);
    return stdscr;
}
```

so

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

std::FILE* cursesout{};
WINDOW* myinitscr() {
    cursesout = std::fopen("/dev/tty", "w");   // open new stream to your terminal
    if(cursesout) newterm(std::getenv("TERM"), cursesout, stdin);
    return stdscr;
}
```

and after `endwin()`:

```cpp
std::fclose(cursesout);
```

---

Alternatively, use a smart pointer to not have to `std::fclose` the new output stream manually:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

using FILE_ptr = std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&std::fclose)>;
FILE_ptr cursesout{nullptr, nullptr};

WINDOW* myinitscr() {
    cursesout = FILE_ptr(std::fopen("/dev/tty", "w"), &std::fclose);
    if(cursesout) newterm(std::getenv("TERM"), cursesout.get(), stdin);
    return stdscr;
}
```

A version not taking the address of a standard library function (which is strictly prohibited) could look like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

using FILE_ptr = std::unique_ptr<FILE, void (*)(FILE*)>;
FILE_ptr cursesout{nullptr, nullptr};

WINDOW* myinitscr() {
    cursesout = FILE_ptr(std::fopen("/dev/tty", "w"), [](FILE* fp) {
        std::fclose(fp);
    });
    if(cursesout) newterm(std::getenv("TERM"), cursesout.get(), stdin);
    return stdscr;
}
```

Comment: Both initscr and newterm updates the stdscr global variable. So it's a drop in replacement (newterm on stdin and /dev/tty VS initscr) ! Thank you, that's perfect.